# Magento2: After delete pub/static folder and making deploy, no css files found

Tags: magento2, css, grunt

I use Magento 2 custom theme and when I made changes to .less file, I wanted to compile files, so I deleted `pub/static` folder and made deploy: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. After that, no css files are found in `pub/static/frontend/<Theme>/default/css`. Also, when I use grunt less, I got errors:

```
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-m.css not written because no source files were found.
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-l.css not written because no source files were found.
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/email.css not written because no source files were found.
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/email-inline.css not written because no source files were found.
```

I am in a developer mode.

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: 'pub/static' should be writable.

Answer (score 12):

You need to run `grunt exec` and then `grunt less`.

Comment: Could not get grunt watch to work after clearing static-content, this solution solved it. Thanks @Aaron!

Comment: Great! Can you mark this as the answer?

Comment: It wasn't my question, just letting other users know this is a working solution :D I wish you many upvotes

Answer (score 2):

It could be because you deleted the `.htaccess` file from `pub/static`. It can be found here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/pub/static/.htaccess. Next time run `rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/*` instead of deleting the directory.